# SSIS Package to change column format & remove hidden characters / white spaces

Tags: sql-server, database, reporting-services, ssis

I have an issue with loading data from an excel spreadsheet to SQL database using SSIS package. It seems to be data columns have different formats or hidden characters which are not accepting by the database so SSIS package is erroring out as a result.

As its not practical to check every single spreadsheet manually, is there a way we can add another SSIS package to check data first and change the format if its needed or remove if there are any hidden characters and then save them in a staging table before run the data loading package?

Comment: Why have you tagged MySQL?

Comment: @DaleBurrell The SO tag recommendation engine sometimes suggests MySQL in an overly-eager way.

Comment: As long as the data in the Excel file is stored as the correct data type, there can't be a fomratting issue. If not, you will have to add more information to your question.

Comment: Thanks Wolfgang, those Excel templates coming from different people and some of them come up with changing the column formats and including hidden characters on the columns. This is happening because the way they load the data to the template, as far as I am aware some people loading data from another system to the template and get the column's data format from there which is not comply with the format of database.
We use SSIS package to transfer data from template to the database. Some templates data going well but some are failed because of above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [link](http://www.techbrothersit.com/2013/07/ssis-replace-multiple-characterswords.html) is give you answer to remove `hidden characters` from columns.
You need to use `Script Component >> Transformation` using `Regex` while data transfer from source excel to SQL Server destination in `Data Flow Task`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help, It seem to be an answer for my question but  I am not very clear how can I apply this to any hidden characters and  white-spaces.
Could I kindly ask you is there a way we can change column data type (format) to "number format" if it's formatted with any other type.
Your help on this would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You can use Derived Column Transformation or Data Conversion Transformation for it.